# Infected Files - what to do

Tags: security

a friend received a notification from her host about infected files and asked me to look at it.  I don't know wordpress or php so I'm a little lost in what I am looking for.  The is the websitescan.txt.  I don't know what I am looking at, hoping someone could give me some direction as to what this report is saying and what I can do to fix the problems. thanks

```
Scan started at - Fri Oct 13 13:42:53 EDT 2017
/htdocs/wp-admin/edit-comments_ver1.php:    
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/css/colors/midnight/colors-rtl_new.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/css/colors/ectoplasm/colors_indesit.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/css/colors/sunrise/colors.min_backup.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/css/colors/ocean/colors-rtl.min_backup.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/network/site-settings_old.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/maint/repair_old.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy_backup.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/js/inline-edit-tax_infoold.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-admin/user/admin_bck_old.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-content/themes/fiore/functions.php: 
LONGDEF.PHP.Spam-Links-009N.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-content/themes/fiore/images/thicklines-2x_noversion.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-content/themes/fiore/js/customizer_new.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/SimplePie/HTTP/Parser_bck_old.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/SimplePie/Content/6f26e1e6_bck_old.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/Text/Diff_ver1.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/utils/mctabs_bck_old.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/wp-langs-en_infoold.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/img/trans_backup.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/07ab1454_indesit.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/hr/plugin.min_backup.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpgallery/plugin.min_indesit.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/htdocs/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/media/plugin_infoold.php: 
JCDEF.Obfus.CreateFunc.BackDoorEval-26.UNOFFICIAL FOUND


----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 23 
Time: 238.961 sec (3 m 58 s) 
Scan ended at - Fri Oct 13 13:46:52 EDT 2017
```

Comment: he/she needs to restore from a known good backup, there is rarely any other way after which you will not get infected again

Comment: I think your best option is to hire someone who does know WordPress and can either advise your friend on the best course of action or take care of the issue for them. Another options is to contact the host and see if they have suggestions on how to solve the issue, they may have a backup. Either way, this is not the best place for discussions as it [lands in off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Maybe ask over at the [Official WordPress Forums](https://wordpress.org/support/forums/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a good full backup of your website, restore your site from it (recommended). Install and set up `WordFence` plugin (as in case of no backup).

If you don't have good backup:

Immediately delete all files from this list. Get a clean copy of your version of WordPress, and clean copy of your theme. Copy over entire theme. Copy over clean `/wp-admin/`, and `/wp-includes/`. Start your website. Install `WordFence` security plugin, activate it, and set up its firewall. Do regular scans to see, if the problem persists, and follow plugin's instructions.

Third option: if you don't feel comfortable, performing above steps yourself,  ask security pros for help.

Comment: thanks - I will have to look into this - doubting there is a backup

Comment: ok gave up, there is only so much editing I can do to remove wordfence out of this answer. this right now looks more like an ad than an actual answer

Answer (score -2):

Just Using FTP or File manager Delete these infected files.. Then login to wp admin and add WordFence Security WordPress plugin. Then monitor the site health in regular basis